# websockets:serve cron job error on shared hosting laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, shared-hosting, laravel-websockets

I am using beyondecode laravel websocket package on my laravel project. I have done all the configurations correctly. On hostinger, set a cron job to serve websocket like

```
/usr/bin/php /home/......../domains/quadque.digital/public_html/crmnotification/artisan websockets:serve --port=65002 --host=217.21.94.123
```

But in output getting an error like:

Starting the WebSocket server on port 65002... RuntimeException Failed to listen on "tcp://217.21.94.123:65002": Address already in use (EADDRINUSE) at domains/quadque.digital/public_html/crmnotification/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:184 180â // @link https://3v4l.org/3qOBl 181â $errno = SocketServer::errno($errstr); 182â } 183â â 184â throw new \RuntimeException( 185â 'Failed to listen on "' . $uri . '": ' . $errstr . SocketServer::errconst($errno), 186â $errno 187â ); 188â } [2m+17 vendor frames [22m 18 domains/quadque.digital/public_html/crmnotification/artisan:37 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Why is this occuring ?

Comment: Based on the error, the server is already using the port `65002`, can you try another port?

Comment: I have tried with different ports but same error